# Limit of Integral with Uniformly Convergent Integrand

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

I'm studying for an upcoming exam in analysis and am focusing on the following problem:

Prove that the limit
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \bigg[ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!} \bigg]^2 dx$$
exists.

I'm looking for some guidance on my proof - I feel justified in what I've come up with, but I can't seem to verify the result in Matlab, so I think I must have gone wrong somewhere. My attempt:

Consider $f_n:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined as $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!}$. We claim that $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x) = e^x$ on $[0,1]$. Accordingly, since 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} = e^x \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
we have that for any $\epsilon >0$, $\exists N$ such that 
$$ |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon $$ 
provided that $n \geq N$. Since this holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, it certainly holds for $x \in [0,1]$, thus we have the desired uniform convergence. Now, since $f_n(x)$ is a sequence of continuous functions ($f_n(x)$ is a polynomial for each $n$), it must hold that $g_n(x) = [f_n(x)]^2$ converges uniformly to $g(x) = f(x)^2 = e^{2x}$ on $[0,1]$ (proved in an earlier problem). Finally, since the convergence of the integrand $g_n(x)$ is uniform, and each $g_n(x)$ is continuous, thus integrable, we have that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \bigg[ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!} \bigg]^2 dx &= \int_0^1 e^{2x} dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} (e^2 - 1). \\
\end{align*} 
Our result is finite, thus the limit exists.

Have I made a mistake at some point?

Comment: Your proof on uniform convergence is not correct. What you have to prove is that $\lim_{n\to \infty }\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0.$ Bust you should have a theorem that tells you that $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}$ converge uniformly on $[0,1]$ (in fact on all compact of $\mathbb R$). Assuming this, the rest is ok.

Comment: @Surb This was my initial thought actually, but I was struggling with finding the supremum. Do you have any advice for how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, the proof is wrong since the convergence of the series definition of the exponential to $e^x$ is not uniform on $\mathbb{R}$. This may help: 
$$
\left|\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}\right)^2-e^{2x} \right|\\
=\left|\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}-e^{x} \right|\left|\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}+e^{x} \right|\\
$$
the first term in the product can be kept uniformly small on $[0,1]$ (see Weirstrass-M test, on this interval, the convergence *is* uniform). The second is bounded by $e^2$, since 
$$
\forall n\in \mathbb{N},\;\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}\leq e^x
$$
so 
$$
\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\left\{
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}+e^{x}\right\} \leq e^2
$$
and you have uniform convergence and may interchange limit and integral and perform a simple integration to find the limit is in fact 
$$
\frac12 (e^2-1)
$$